# How to use Dirac delta sifting property to prove question?

Tags: proof-writing, dirac-delta

For my own understanding, how do I prove [this equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3qb5.png) using the Dirac delta sifting property?

Equation to prove: (A)*delta(t-to) + (B)*delta(t-to) = (A+B)*delta(t-to)

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq) to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.

Answer (score 0):

It is just the distributive property.  Whatever $\delta(t-t_0)$ is (I know, but it doesn't matter here) the equation is true.  You don't need the shifting property.

Comment: True, but I was told that we can prove it using the sifting property so I wanted to see how to do that.

Comment: @entropy283: I think that ross-millikan's point is that if the sifting property is among the facts you are already _given_ about the Dirac delta, then the equation you want to prove is also already given. Since the Dirac delta involves integration and since integration is distributive, the distributive property (which you want to prove) is available _before_ the sifting property is introduced or proved.